# Unwantedly attribute injection wfd-id="xx" in all html div tags

Tags: php, html, browser, attributes, code-injection

One of my site users generates in jce editor wired html code on saving. His saved code got in all div and input tags a new attribute `wfd-id="xx".` This behaviour makes it impossible to generate a pdf with mpdf from the site.

Is this a browser extension which injected this weird tag?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<h3>In sämtlichen unter Punkt 1 bis 4 mit "Ja" angekreuzten Situationen verlange ich folgendes</h3>

<div wfd-id="185">
<div class="box_checkbox" wfd-id="187"><input type="checkbox" wfd-id="288" checked="checked" selected="selected"></div>

<div class="box_checkbox_text" wfd-id="186">auf Maßnahmen zu verzichten, die bloß den Eintritt des Todes verzögern</div>
</div>

<div wfd-id="182">
<div class="box_checkbox" wfd-id="184"><input type="checkbox" wfd-id="287" checked="checked" selected="selected"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is the Kaspersky password manager.